# How to estimate performance and capacity requirements for SharePoint Server 2013 Search

Tags: search, 2013

My customer has asked for guidance on total index sizes in SharePoint 2013. Does anybody have visibility of what people should be planning for?

Per [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750251.aspx) on MSDN, In SharePoint 2010 you should anticipate that your index size is .035 of the size of your contentdbsum. Has this changed? If yes, by how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all that has been published so far that I have seen [MSDN Database requirements for SP2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section3)

It states to see 2010, so in answer no, it appears not to have changed.

A personal caveat however is that the indexer has new modes, with these turned on this would of course increase usage.

Comment: It's definitely not something they've published but the link you provided is the right place for it to live. Apparently my client has been told by Microsoft that index size will decrease, but I'm a bit sceptical.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this TechNet [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219628%28office.15%29.aspx). It talks about search performance and availability. It provides hardware requirements, as well as scaling and redundancy considerations. It is not as thorough as the SP 2010 article you mentioned, but it is a start.